FBX Export changes position of one object
When I export my armature with its mesh to FBX, then one of the meshes moves slightly, seemingly without reason. All transforms have been applied, and I even tried Apply Transform during export, which only makes things worse.
In the attached blend file, I reduced my project to the bare minimum: the rig with one bone, and the icosphere parented to said bone, not via weight painting.


The above image is how it looks before exporting.

The above image is how it looks after importing the exported FBX.

I'm unsure as to why, but what fixed this problem was unparenting the mesh from the bone, apply transforms of both objects (even though everything was applied already), then parenting the mesh back to the bone.
